# go xray sdk in lambda to capture calls to redis

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am trying to implement golang xray sdk in LAMBDA to capture calls going to redis (AWS managed). Is there a documentation that I can refer for that or any directions to do that.

I am using go-redis to makes calls to redis server.